# Unparseable date (datepicker) - Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, date

I'm working on a web application that uses spring and hibernate & bootstrap,
I want to update a table that the primary key is "Date",
But I got `Unparseable Date: ""` error when updating the table,

this is my jsp

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="workingdate" text="default text" /></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input id="WORKING_DATE_U" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="WORKING_DATE_F" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" required></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a href="#update" role="button" id="btn_update" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"><i
        class="icon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<spring:message code="updatel" text="default text" /></a>
        <br><br>
    <!-- delete -->
    <div id="update" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <form action="updateKSEI.html" method="post">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel"><spring:message code="updatewd" text="default text" /></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 align="center"><spring:message code="areYouSure" text="default text" /></h4>
                <input type="hidden" id="WORKING_DATE_D" name="WORKING_DATE" required>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><spring:message code="no" text="default text" /></button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<spring:message code="yes" text="default text" />">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

this is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var nowTemp = new Date();
            var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

            var checkin = $('#WORKING_DATE_U').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay:function(date){
                    return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf();
                },
                autoclose:true
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev){
                {
                    var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
                    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);

                }
            });

            $('.update').click(function(){
                $('#WORKING_DATE_D').val(checkin);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/updateKSEI.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateKSEI(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{

    Date WORKING_DATE = this.dateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("WORKING_DATE"));
    UpdateKSEI updateksei = updatekseiService.get(WORKING_DATE);

    String SISTEM = updateksei.getSISTEM();
    String DESCRIPTION = updateksei.getDESCRIPTION();
    String FLAG = updateksei.getFLAG();

    updateksei.setWORKING_DATE(WORKING_DATE);
    updateksei.setSISTEM(SISTEM);
    updateksei.setDESCRIPTION(DESCRIPTION);
    updateksei.setFLAG("Y");
    updatekseiService.update(updateksei);
    model.addAttribute("successUpdate", "true");
    System.out.println(FLAG);
    return listKSEI(model);
}
```

and I've parse the date before : `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");`

and I still got the `Unparseable Date: ""` error,

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Looks like you parse an empty string as Date!

Comment: @Jens If so, what should I do??

Comment: @Jens I think, I've set the value of the hidden variable with this script `$('.update').click(function(){$('#WORKING_DATE_D').val(checkin);});` isn't enough??

Comment: @Jens Yeah, I've test it before, and that script is send the empty string... so how I get the value from the `id=WORKING_DATE_U` any idea??

Comment: @Jens I've add your scriptl but I got this `Unparseable date: "WORKING_DATE_U"` error ~

Comment: @Jens still send the empty string, sorry for your first script send the empty string too... FYI: `var checkin` on my script is datapicker... is that the cause??